# React router fail to load external library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using **create-react-app** to create my project, after that I setup 2 components: **Home** and **Article**, both of them need an external library to work (https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './home';
import Article from './article';

class Codelab extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/article/:id" component={Article} />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

I try typing url directly to the address bar: *"/"* or *"/article/1"*, and everything work as expected. Later, I use **Link** from **react-router-dom** to allow user to go to article page just by clicking on an icon.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       // a lot of unrelevant code here

       <Link to="/article/1"><p className="mdl-button">Take the course</p></Link>

       // a lot of unrelevant code here
    )
  }
}
```

For some reason **Article** page does not load the **material.min.js** library, and it's layout break.

[image]

If I reload that page or access it directly by typing url, the result is different.

[image]

Update: There are no errors showing in console, and here my **Article** component:

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Article extends React.Component {
  // componentDidMount() {

  // }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="demo-layout mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer mdl-layout--fixed-header">
        <header className="demo-header mdl-layout__header mdl-color--grey-100 mdl-color-text--grey-600">
          <div className="mdl-layout__header-row">
            <span className="mdl-layout-title">Omena tutorial basic</span>
            <div className="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
            <div className="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable">
              <label className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" htmlFor="search">
                <Link to="/"><i className="material-icons">arrow_forward</i></Link>
              </label>
              <div className="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
        <div className="demo-drawer mdl-layout__drawer mdl-color--blue-grey-900 mdl-color-text--blue-grey-50">
          <header className="demo-drawer-header">
            <div className="demo-avatar-dropdown">
              <span>hello@example.com</span>
              <div className="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
              <button id="accbtn" className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--icon">
                <i className="material-icons" role="presentation">arrow_drop_down</i>
                <span className="visuallyhidden">Accounts</span>
              </button>
              <ul className="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" htmlFor="accbtn">
                <li className="mdl-menu__item">hello@example.com</li>
                <li className="mdl-menu__item">info@example.com</li>
                <li className="mdl-menu__item">
                  <i className="material-icons">add</i>Add another account...</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </header>
          <nav className="demo-navigation mdl-navigation mdl-color--blue-grey-800">
            <a className="mdl-navigation__link" >
              <i className="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">forward</i>Step 1</a>
            <a className="mdl-navigation__link" >
              <i className="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">forward</i>Step 2</a>
            <a className="mdl-navigation__link" >
              <i className="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">forward</i>Step 3</a>
            <a className="mdl-navigation__link" >
              <i className="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">forward</i>Step 4</a>
            <div className="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
            <a className="mdl-navigation__link" >
              <i className="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">assignment</i>Exercise 1</a>
            <a className="mdl-navigation__link" >
              <i className="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">assignment</i>Exercise 2</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <main className="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">
          <div className="mdl-grid demo-content">
            <div className="demo-charts mdl-color--white mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-grid">
              <div className="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
                <div className="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                  <h4>Step 1</h4>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas scelerisque dolor et posuere tempus. Lorem ipsum dolor
              sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas scelerisque dolor et posuere tempus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
              amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas scelerisque dolor et posuere tempus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
              consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas scelerisque dolor et posuere tempus.
              <br />
                  <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas scelerisque dolor et posuere tempus. Lorem
              ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas scelerisque dolor et posuere tempus. Lorem ipsum
              dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas scelerisque dolor et posuere tempus. Lorem ipsum dolor
              sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas scelerisque dolor et posuere tempus.
            </div>
                <div className="mdl-card__actions mdl-navigation">
                  <a className="mdl-button">Previous</a>
                  <div className="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                  <a className="mdl-button">Next</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Article;
```

Comment: `Article` might be having some error. Could you post that component as well?

Comment: Side note: this library (mdlite), has discontinued development. Google is now working on https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web. Just an FYI, it looks like you're starting a new project.

Comment: Could you take a network snapshot and paste the results here? Also, where is the css include?